# Bootstrap img src not loading images from local hard drive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing an amazing problem that my html program loads images from web but not from local hard drive. I tried alot by changing path and folder but still the issue is same.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <figure>
            <img src="/images/img.jpg"
                 alt="Ghoomo Phiro Pakistan Adventure Club">
        </figure>
        <div class="caption">
            EveryThing goes there
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
                 alt="Ghoomo Phiro Pakistan Adventure Club">
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            EveryThing goes there
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why does this work:

```
<img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"
    src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sr/0/0c/Firefox-logo.png"
    alt="" />
```

But not local images:

```
<img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"
     src="http://localhost/live/images/logo.png"
     alt="" />
```

Comment: In above code the 1st one is not working but 2nd path works by loading image from web.

Comment: Probably because the image path is wrong. Inspect the element using Firebug console and see if the image is loading up there

Comment: Tylenol's exactly right I should have placed it in the comment field....moving on.

Comment: @Baber can show  heirarchy of html page  and Images folder in same folder .

Comment: @yugi its a MVC project and I'm working in VS 2013 for web.

Comment: @yugi
The hirearchy is as:
Home (folder) -- images ( folder) -->img.jpg (image)
and all the .cshtml files are in home folder

Comment: @Baber then open web console.go to network Tab and check what is error showing.may u don't have permission in that folder

Answer (score 4):

If you use src="/images/fileName" then the browser looks for images folder in the root directory. If images folder is in the same working directory then it won't work. You must have to replace it with either ./images/fileName or images/fileName

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your image is in one directory, and your css file in another. If this is the case, your css file will not be able to access the image without first going up the in the directory like so:

```
<img src="../images/img.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it when my image moved from assets/images to views/* or public. Also you can use image_tag Rails helper.